# CPanel Finished install..now what?

Tags: linux

My organization currently has an account with `www.greengeeks.com` where we use cPanel to manage a handful of LAMP apps.

We wanted to move our server and apps in house. So I we purchased cPanel, and I have just finished setup of the server and the cPanel install.

So now what?

I thought I would see the cPanel view/screens that I see over at greengeeks, but instead I don't see any of that. Things like FTP, and MySQL ... ect.

Looks like when I login to whm, I am one level above what I see in my greengeeks view. How do I set that up?

Better yet, is there a migration path to easily move stuff from greengeeks to my own server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Webhost Manager* (or WHM) is the view for the, well, web host's manager, or in cPanel terms, the *Reseller*. Within WHM resellers (including `root`) create new cPanel accounts under **Account Functions > Create a New Account**. It's these accounts which access *cPanel*. cPanel is the UI for the admin *of a single web account*, WHM is the UI for the admin *of the entire server*

WebHost Manager is located at `https://your-server:2087/`

cPanel is located at `https://your-server:2083/`

Once you create accounts under **Account Functions > Create a New Account**, you can view the list of accounts under **Account Functions > List Accounts**. Each account has a green `CP` icon next to it:

[image: CP Icon]

Clicking those icons will take you to the cPanel UI for that account.

Comment: Glad I could help!